# How does one drop lowest and reroll ones/lowest in the context of multiple sides of dice?

Tags: dice

I am making a dice rolling app and am trying to implement dice roll features. I want my features to apply to any game. Are there other common functions in addition to the ones I have mentioned? Here is an example of my question.

Example: 
If the player rolls 2d4 + 3d6 and gets

d4: 1, 1 | d6: 1, 4, 1

Drop lowest - would that get rid of one 1 in both the d4 and d6?

Reroll ones - would that reroll all 1's from both dice? Should it make sure the outcome contains no 1's?

Reroll lowest - would that reroll all the 1's from both dice?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the desired functionality of an app which does not exist.

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic, but it's definitely too broad - it's asking about dice mechanics in every RPG in existence.

Comment: However the rules in question say to; there's no generic answer, since it could be done as many different ways as designers could imagine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wanted to put that as a comment, but I believe it would be a better answer and help the asker in a way beyond question's scope.

While it's admirable effort to develop a dice rolling application usable in **ALL** systems, its impossible to predict all required rolling schemes. Ever heard of [One Roll Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-Roll_Engine) or exploding dice?

### Notable modern rolling engines no longer aim to be rollers with preset rolling scenarios, instead becoming dice rolling script interpreters.

Sorry to burst your bubble.

Comment: +1.  OP, c.f. [AnyDice](http://anydice.com/), which our ads link to regularly.